# how to upgrade moodle from version 1.9 to 2.2 without legacy files

Tags: moodle

How to go about upgrading moodle without all coursefiles going to the legacy folders?

I have tried re mapping files and creating links in the course area to the files that worked, but i am wondering if their any other way of going about it? Possibly upgrading further to 2.3+ could fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to upgrade moodle version from 1.9 to 2.2.

Please go through following url

> http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Upgrading_to_Moodle_2.2

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is on how to upgrae the software, what it doesn't tell you that you have to go through the data migration process which requires a large amount of time. Currently I have tried: database remapping to remap files and restoring courses in 2.2. Having 100GB of course files to restore takes about a week :/ it be nicer to work out a quicker way. With database remapping i was looking at 3-4 days, which is far quicker but not a good way at all.